# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

I am relatively new to C# and i have come across this error while working on a project to spin a VM (and support resources in MS Azure).

The code I am using is the one below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION"));
            var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();
```

Also I have an "azureauth.properties.txt" file i used to set a new Environmental path referenced in the code above as `"AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION"`.

To set the path i used the simple  PS command:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION", "C:\MY-PATH\azureauth.properties", "User")
```

The azureauth.properties file contains simple Tenant/application/key IDs in the format

```
subscription=<subscription-id>
client=<application-id>
key=<authentication-key>
tenant=<tenant-id>
managementURI=https://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https://management.azure.com/
authURL=https://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https://graph.windows.net/
```

Whenever I am trying to run the project i get an error saying:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'

specifically for the line:

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION"));
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Check the result from *Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION")* - seems it is null and therefore you have to examine why the environment variable is unknown to the process

Comment: Could you add the stack trace for better assistance?

Comment: Please have a try restart Visual Studio and try again then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Like luxun said, you have to define the environment variable.
For that open the cmd (on windows) and write:

> set AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION

this will show the environment variable "AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION". If the result is "Environment variable AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION not defined" or if the path is wrong then write on the cmd:

> SET AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION=PathOfTheAzureAuthLocationFile

This should do the trick.

Comment: I have done this but unfortunately same issue. I still receive the error in VS

Comment: If you set an environment variable like this, then it is only valid for that process and all child processes created after it was set. You should keep that in mind

Comment: @Steba do you still get the error? Can you share the stacktrace?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION")` must be returning null.

If this is the case you may want to check if that environment variable has actually been defined or whether the file exists.

Define a variable like:

```
var location = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION");
```

When you debug in VS you should be able to inspect the value of location by right clicking on it and clicking quickwatch.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your suggestions. 
in the end the error was generated by a school-boy mistake in setting the Env Variable in the first place (relative path contained an error I didn't spot earlier).

I was able to run it in the end.

Made a change to define the path in the config file instead too.

thanks